# How to traverse in nested array and insert element in mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb, I want to traverse a nested array document and insert a new array in that document. I'm not sure how to traverse in this tree structure document.

Here's my code:

```
dataList = {"code": '1', "sensor_name": 'digital',"type": 'rpm'}

db.datapoints.update_one(
                {'sites.areas.lines.line_name': 'Press Line'},
                {"$push": {'sites.areas.lines.resources':[dataList]}}
            )
```

My existing document:

```
{
  "org_name": "VISION", 
  "org_id": "58d2b48760bfd71bbc7bbf2a", 
  "sites": 
  [
    {
      "site_code": "af2df470-1b97-4763-a80c-f704eefa295a", "site_name": 
      "Office", 
      "areas": 
      [
        {
          "lines": 
          [
            {
              "line_code": "1daed5e5-a4cd-4644-98a1", 
              "line_name": "Line", 
           }, 
           {
              "line_code": "40abea9f-329c",
              "line_name": "Ovens", 
           }
         ], 
         "area_name": "Manufacturing", 
         "area_code": "4a47c299-ff3c-4426-a511"
      }
    ]     
  }
]
}
```

After Execute the query I want like this:

```
{
  "org_name": "VISION", 
  "org_id": "58d2b48760bfd71bbc7bbf2a", 
  "sites": 
  [
    {
      "site_code": "af2df470-1b97-4763-a80c-f704eefa295a", "site_name": 
      "Office", 
      "areas": 
      [
        {
          "lines": 
          [
            {
              "line_code": "1daed5e5-a4cd-4644-98a1", 
              "line_name": "Line", 
              "resources": 
              [
                {
                  "code": "1", 
                  "sensor_name": "digital",
                  "type": "rpm"  
                }
             ]    
           }, 
           {
              "line_code": "40abea9f-329c",
              "line_name": "Ovens",
           }
         ], 
         "area_name": "Manufacturing", 
         "area_code": "4a47c299-ff3c-4426-a511"
      }
    ]     
  }
]
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do this? I've been stuck on this for so many hours.

Comment: You really should not nest arrays. Though there is "coming support" for this, it's still generally best to think in design terms. Your "nestings" here really should be attributes on the the innermost detail. Don't try and model arrays based on multiple table relations. Try for a single array, and even with the next MongoDB release, have an inner depth "at most".

Comment: my requirement like this.. Is possible or not?

Comment: This Query working for me. But how do i know the position. Anything operator to replace 0.                            db.datapoints.update(
            { 'sites.areas.lines.line_name': event['line_name'] },
            { "$push": { "sites.0.areas.0.lines.1.resources": dataList}}
        )